# opencl - cost of creation image

Tags: opencl

In my host program, i checked time for creating image.

it takes 0.03 seconds for just creation without copying.

it take longer than execution time of some kernel why this thing happened?

```
     fmt.image_channel_order=CL_RG;
     fmt.image_channel_data_type =CL_FLOAT;
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_start_temp);
    cl::Image2D  test_image=cl::Image2D(gContext,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,fmt,width,height,0,NULL);//width= 2560 height=1440
         clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_end_temp);
    time_elapsed = getTimeElapsed(time_end_temp, time_start_temp);
                        LOGI("image copy TIME, %f ", time_elapsed);


    float getTimeElapsed(struct timespec end, struct timespec start) {
    struct timespec temp;
    float res;

    temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec - 1;
    if ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) < 0) {
        temp.tv_nsec = 1e9 + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    }
    res = ((float) temp.tv_sec) + ((float) temp.tv_nsec / 1e9);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Some platforms have issues allocating memory, like ARM/Qualcom, and may take long time to find you empty blocks to store the image size. This issue only happens during the first allocation.

Comment: @DarkZeros Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show all your code but if there are clEnqueue calls ahead of creating the image, *some* runtimes will do an implicit clFinish before creating your image and so your 30 ms might include that. This is because the image and buffer allocation and free calls are synchronous while the command queue functions are asynchronous and the driver is not being optimal. If you put a clFinish before your test, does the timing change? What runtime are you using?